# How to switch rust-analyzer from stable to nightly in vscode?

Tags: rust, vscode-extensions

The default rust toolchain on the machine is already set to nightly. But rust-analyzer complains about unstable features in vscode.

```
"#![feature] may not be used on the stable release channel"
```

It seems that rust-analyzer in vscode doesn't honor the toolchain setting on the machine. Is there a way to switch rust-analyzer from stable to nightly in vscode?

Answer (score 12):

If your toolchain (and `rust-analyzer` with it) is managed by `rustup` you can simply put a toolchain-file in your project directory (next to `Cargo.toml`) or use any other [toolchain override](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html)

rust-toolchain.toml:

```ini
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly"
```

It might require reloading VSCode for it to take effect.